# Why do I keep getting null in this ternary assignment?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this function with a fetch:

```
getHistory(){
        console.log("Log antes del fetch de customer id");
        console.log(this.state.customer._id);
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/orders/customer/'+this.state.customer._id, {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                responseData.map(function (v) {
                    v.orderStatusChange = v.order ? v.order.orderStatusChange : null  })
                this.setState({orders:responseData})
                console.log("Log del responseData");
                console.log(responseData);

            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

I get an array of objects with responseData, which looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG4kc.png). I want to access orderStatusChange and get the status. I've been able to get other values from the array like the id of the order or the date that was created putting the key of the array directly in the table where they have to be printed:

```
const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: '_id',
        label: 'Número de pedido'
    }, {
        key: 'created',
        label: 'Fecha del pedido'
    }, {
        key: 'status',
        label: 'Estado'
    }
];
```

Looking like this now: [TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLOux.png)

But since status is inside another array within the main array, I thought that I could map it to get it as shown in the function:

```
responseData.map(function (v) {
                v.orderStatusChange = v.order ? v.order.orderStatusChange : null  })
```

But orderStatusChange keeps getting null as value.

How could I get the status value?

EDIT: Adding part of the Json object instead of a capture:

```
(29) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
created:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
customer:"59561f3f1d178e1966142ad7"
lastModified:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
orderList:[]
orderStatusChange:Array(1)
0:{status: "5", comments: "Creado en back antes de pagar", _id: "595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7c", created: "2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
shop:"59108159bc3fc645704ba508"
totalAmount:4000
__v:0
_id:"595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7b"
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Please add the responseData JSON to the question rather than as a linked image, thanks

Comment: Which data are you trying to display in table. Looking at your json, you are displaying 'created' and 'id' from responseData and you want status to be displayed which is not present in your responseData. As you are trying to get status from orderStatusChange which is an array, i am assuming every record in it may have different status.

Comment: I try to display, as you said, "id" and "created" from responseData, and "status" within orderStatusChange array (and yes, status is variable). How can I access it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your json there is no `order` property in your object.
This is why you always go in the `false` section of the ternary operator.

Not related to your question, but having a `.map` not being followed by any consumers look pretty useless.

Comment: How should I construct the `.map`? It's my first time using it. Consumer ID is passed through the DOMAIN.

Comment: I don't know i depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Just to get the status value and print it on the table.

Comment: which one? `orderStatusChange` is an array. And this question is more a react concern, it depend how you handle tour state.

Comment: I keep the Json object obtained in `this.state.orders`, being `orders: []`.

Comment: I get that, but setting thing like that in the state is not going to diplay nothing. You need to handle the state. Since it's not relatd to this question you should probably open a new question asking exactly for what you need now. And show more code, so we could help you